# Using different proto files for server and client in gRPC

Tags: grpc

I have one proto file for gRPC server

```
service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloReply {
  string othermessage = 1;
  string message = 2;
  string othermessage2 = 3;
}
```

My client don't need the fields othermessage and othermessage2. I make other proto file for client

```
service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 2;
}
```

It works, but is it correct?

I see the following advantages: the client receive only the necessary data, the client's proto-file is not overloaded. For example, in sql we get only the required fields.

Maybe it's more efficient? Are all fields transmitted over the network or only the requested one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the article [Analyzing gRPC messages using Wireshark](https://grpc.io/blog/wireshark/) to validate fields sent over the network. All fields are sent. Therefore, using truncated proto files does not increase efficiency.

As a result, we can use the truncated proto file on the client, if it contains non-breaking differences, by analogy with [non-breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/versioning?view=aspnetcore-6.0). This does not increase performance and can only be used to reduce the proto file on the client side.